# Slow Query Due to Sub Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have several SQL Server 2014 queries that pull back a data set where we need to get a count on related, but different criteria along with that data. We do this with a sub query, but that is slowing it down immensely. It was fine until now where we are getting more data in our database to count on.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    T.*, 
    ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(1)
            FROM EventRegTix ERT, EventReg ER
            WHERE ER.EventRegID = ERT.EventRegID 
              AND ERT.TicketID = T.TicketID
              AND ER.OrderCompleteFlag = 1), 0) AS NumTicketsSold
FROM 
    Tickets T 
WHERE 
    T.EventID = 12345
    AND T.DeleteFlag = 0 
    AND T.ActiveFlag = 1
ORDER BY 
    T.OrderNumber ASC
```

I am pretty sure its mostly due to the relation back outside of the sub query to the `Tickets` table. If I change the `T.TicketID` to an actual ticket # (999 for example), the query is MUCH faster.

I have attempted to join together these queries into one, but since there are other fields in the sub query, I just cannot get it to work properly. I was playing around with

```
COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY T.TicketID) AS NumTicketsSold
```

but could not figure that out either.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Why not simply left join to EventRegTix and EventReg instead of the subquery. Also, you really should start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Sidenote: This old style join syntax is about 25 years old. You should use new style joins. (from table A AS A INNER JOIN TableB AS B ON A.Id = B.ID...)

Comment: And how big are the tables? Also, pretty pretty please don't use comm-syntax joins.

Comment: I think your correlated subquery is fine here other than some small syntax changes. You could just join your three tables together in a single `FROM` clause as well and then use a GROUP BY for all of your `t.*` fields, but that's unnecessary really. I don't think that's the reason you are running slow though. A lack of proper indexing is probably the most likely culprit.

Comment: SQL 2014  @Sean, yes.  We have been migrating the queries.  This is an older site.  I change the queries as I find them, will do this one when I figure out the faster option.  thanks

Comment: I did check indexing.  TicketID and EventRegID are both PK / FK of their respective main tables.  I dont think anything else needs an index?

Comment: Can you  post an execution plan? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Execution plan pointed out the issue - no index on the EventRegTix table for EventRegID (it is a FK). Indexing now... more soon.  THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
SELECT T.*, 
       (SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM EventRegTix ERT JOIN
             EventReg ER
             ON ER.EventRegID = ERT.EventRegID 
        WHERE ERT.TicketID = T.TicketID AND ER.OrderCompleteFlag = 1
      ) AS NumTicketsSold
FROM Tickets T 
WHERE T.EventID = 12345 AND
      T.DeleteFlag = 0 AND
      T.ActiveFlag = 1
ORDER BY T.OrderNumber ASC;
```

Proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax does not improve performance; it is just the correct syntax. `COUNT(*)` cannot return `NULL` values, so `COALESCE()` or a similar function is unnecessary.

You need indexes.  The obvious ones are on `Tickets(EventID, DeleteFlag, ActiveFlag, OrderNumber)`, `EventRegTix(TicketID, EventRegID)`, and `EventReg(EventRegID, OrderCompleteFlag)`.

Comment: "You need indexes." <<<< This. :-)

Comment: This query is no faster.  I dont know what else to index??

Answer (score 1):

I would try with `OUTER APPLY` :

```
SELECT T.*, T1.*
FROM Tickets T OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT COUNT(1) AS NumTicketsSold
      FROM EventRegTix ERT JOIN
           EventReg ER
           ON ER.EventRegID = ERT.EventRegID 
        WHERE ERT.TicketID = T.TicketID AND ER.OrderCompleteFlag = 1
      ) T1
WHERE T.EventID = 12345 AND
      T.DeleteFlag = 0 AND
      T.ActiveFlag = 1
ORDER BY T.OrderNumber ASC;
```

And, obvious you need indexes `Tickets(EventID, DeleteFlag, ActiveFlag, OrderNumber), EventRegTix(TicketID, EventRegID), and EventReg(EventRegID, OrderCompleteFlag)` to gain the performance.

Comment: Do you need indexes on ANY field that has a criteria against it?  I am not a DBA (!!), but I did not think that true/false fields needed indexes.  T.EventID - that's one I might have missed.  Are FK's indexed by default or just PK?

Comment: Ugh, I think that is my issue.  FK not indexed by default, let me index and come back to this issue.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this - query went from 5+ seconds to 1/2 second or less.  Issues were:

1) No indexes.  Did not know all FK fields needed indexes as well.  I indexed all the fields that we joined or were in WHERE clause.

2) Used SQL Execution Plan to see the place where the bottle neck was.  Told me no index, hence 1) above! :)

Thanks for all your help guys, hopefully this post helps someone else.

Dennis

PS: Changed the syntax too!

Comment: You might want to read up on [covering indexes](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) and included columns.

Comment: yep, will review